# Lerping between values of rotations causes a position change of the gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d-model

### **The situation**

In my game, I have a boat and it is following my finger anywhere on the screen (or the mouse with a raycast just for testing). I didn't want to use animations for the movements or physics because of what I am trying to achieve (animations don't feel well for a boat movement and physics are just to complex for what I am doing).

This is my movement and rotation controls:

```
 if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
       {
            
            Vector3 target = hit.point;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,
             new Vector3(target.x, transform.position.y, target.z), speed);

            if(target.x - transform.position.x > 0)
            {
                right = true;
                isIdle = false;
            }
            else
            {
                right = false;
                isIdle = false;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        isIdle = true;
        
        if (transform.rotation == originalRotation)
        {
            restoreRotation = false;
        }
        else
        {
            restoreRotation = true;
        }

        if (restoreRotation)
        {
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, originalRotation, Time.deltaTime * 5);
        }
```

That is why I added **3 coroutines**, one for the idle rotation, one for the rotation to the right and one to the left. For example, this is the coroutine of right movement:

```
IEnumerator rightAnimation(float time)
{
    while (true)
    {

        if (right == true && isIdle == false)
        {
            float elapsedTime = 0;

            if (transform.rotation != Quaternion.Euler(-2, 13, -8))
            {

                while (elapsedTime < time)
                {
                    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(-2, 13, -8), (elapsedTime / time));
                    elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

                    yield return null;
                }
            }

            elapsedTime = 0;

            while (elapsedTime < time)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Quaternion.Euler(-2, 13, -8), Quaternion.Euler(-7, 13, -8), (elapsedTime / time));
                elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

                yield return null;
            }

            elapsedTime = 0;

            while (elapsedTime < time)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(Quaternion.Euler(-7, 13, -8), Quaternion.Euler(-2, 13, -8), (elapsedTime / time));
                elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

                yield return null;
            }
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }
```

If `right == true` then my coroutine checks the rotation and lerp to the new rotation. I checked the values on the inspector and it looked fine, just like this:

[image]

**There is no position change** and this was perfect because the position is controlled by a `MoveTowards` very simple.

When I try my code in the game, coroutines work fine and they are looping in the right way but this happens:

[image]

My camera is not able to follow the center of the boat, without animations was following fine, and the boat is moving a bit in the right than my finger and sometimes it even broke the coroutines because if I keep dragging the finger to the right, it looks like I am still on the boat but then Unity thinks I am moving to the left and so it quickly changes the animation and also moving like 2-3 units to the left, like teleporting.

I first thought it was a problem of **pivot** but the boat it's actually just an empty gameObject and inside the model of the boat and it is all centered:

[image]

I have no clue, I am not changing the position in any way with that Lerp between rotations, so I don't have an idea about this

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem from the code in the question. Debugging questions need to have enough information to be reproducible to be considered on-topic. Please edit the question to include enough info and see [mre] for more information.

Comment: ok editing it now @Ruzihm

Comment: You dont have any code controlling the camera? It is no surprise it doesn't move...

Comment: I thought it was useless, it's just a cinemachine that follows the player, the camera thing it's just a problem that is caused by the position problem or the rotation that is moving the boat. Camera is moving fine, with the animation it's just a bit offsetted when I turn @Ruzihm

Comment: so you are using some sort of animation right?did you check the transform rect in the animation? make sure that the position is not changing in your animation

Comment: I'm not using an animation, I'm animating my boat with the coroutines, like the one to the right that I have put the code. That's no position changing inside them @AfiJaabb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved the problem by removing the cinemachine, basically, it was creating these problems:

1. It was following the rotation of the boat and that was causing strange perspectives
2. The change of the rotation was changing the direction of the raycast, causing the boat to quickly change and glitch its position

With a new camera and a code made by me, it is now working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

## you didn't make the camera follow the boat via code?

If I'm right, Just add a script make the camera following the boat and everything should works fine... I guess

Comment: Im Sorry but that's not the case, camera follows the boat with the cinemachine and it works fine without the coroutine. But when I added the right and left rotation it follows the boat with a little offset, like the boat is not in the center anymore. The main problem is not the camera, it's the rotation of the boat @MohammedThaier